Flyback Diode Question
I would like to have a quick review of my circuit diagram. I want to ensure my flyback diode is correct and I have a sufficient diode for my use case.
I am using a LiPo battery (4.2 V max / 3.7 V nominal) connecting to a header which will have an external coil placed on it (1-2 ohms). The power across this coil will be controlled by a gate and will allow power to the coil a few times an hour (~3 seconds each time).
Is my circuit correct (is the flyback diode correctly oriented +/-)?
Diode: SS24L.
Circuit Diagram:


Your schematic symbol is wrong- a Zener diode rather than a Schottky.
In any case, if your driver has a high-side switch then the orientation is correct.
The peak diode current could be in excess of 4A (4.2A, to be specific, if the coil is 1Ω), but is probably okay with a 2A diode since it's infrequent and of short duration. A lower voltage Schottky may be better since it will have less Vf at 4A and there is no need to block more than 5V.

Flyback diodes should always be connected to the terminals of the coil or inductor, since the inductor will generate a (huge) negative voltage across it's terminals. If you are designing a pcb, keep it very close to the coil.

Also I would recommend a general-purpose diode like the 1N4007, but you would have to calculate the power generated by your coil and look if your diode can handle the watts.
Further reading: How to choose a flyback diode for a relay?

It should be closest to the switch, actually; with a bypass capacitor nearby as well.  How close, depends on the speed of the switch. A load switch IC or protected MOSFET may switch slow enough that it doesn't matter until some meters distance (but then again, these devices are usually internally protected so that the external diode isn't required).

@TimWilliams Why close to the switch? I've always placed "snubbers" close to the source of the noise to keep the current loop small. This way the spikes have less chance of coupling/radiate on their way to the flyback diode.

@Aaron The switch is quite literally the source, in a very deep (causal) sense -- the coil is just doing what the switch "tells" it to do.  It might be the case that the coil dominates the loop (say, 10s mH vs. 1s of µH) -- but you will find that this advice applies truly in general, from mechanical contacts to switching power supplies to RF amplifiers. Whereas putting it just at the coil, will eventually land you in trouble -- maybe one could argue such a situation is ill conceived (according to some other criterion), but this is the precise physical reason.

Indeed, spikes "coupling/radiat[ing]" implies high frequencies, at least some MHz (risetimes <1µs), and commensurate length cabling to act as antenna; if we don't terminate the EMC loop locally, and filter away from the wires, we have exactly this emissions problem; no amount of filtering or diode-clamping at the far (coil) end can address this. :) Another point of reference: cables contribute stray inductance (as measured at low frequencies) in the 0.5µH/m ballpark; often, cables can be short enough not to matter (hence what I said above), but eventually it will bite back.
